# How do I find out if an object is the last in an array (in Swift language)

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, swift4.2

I have the following code in Swift 4.2.1

```
for myTask in myTasks {
    if myTask === myTasks.last! {
        // Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'Task' operands
    }
}

myTasks.forEach({ myTask in
    if myTask == myTasks.last! {
        // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Task' operands
    }
})
```

and Xcode show the error in the comments.

What I want to do is test if the object being iterated is the last object in the array? How can I code that? Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to conform to [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol

Comment: or you can use `enumerated()` method on your array, which passes element along with it's index inside for loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first attempt with `===` would require tasks to be classes (`===` compares references). Your second attempt would require tasks to be `Equatable`. However, even if you implement `Equatable`, it's not a good idea to use `==` to check whether the task is the last one in the array.

What you want to do is usually done using index:

```
for (offset, myTask) in myTasks.enumerated() {
   if offset + 1 == myTasks.count {

   }
}
```

This is generally safer because it prevents issues when the same `task` appears multiple times in the array.

Another option is to separate code for both cases (might not be the best option for you):

```
for myTask in myTasks.dropLast() {
   // handle all tasks except the last one
}

if let lastTask = myTasks.last {
   // handle last task
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not an issue here, but generally “offset” need not be the collection index (e.g. for array slices).

Comment: @MartinR I know, I would not want to use `offset` with `dropLast`.

Comment: If you want the indices, you can `zip(myTasks.indices, myTasks)`. If you want to use `enumerated`, you'd need to compare to `count - 1` rather than `indices.last`.

Comment: @RobNapier You are right, it's probably a better solution not to mix the two although it makes no difference for `Array`.